# jQuery Ajax Response: Works in Browser, Null on Mobile Device

Tags: jquery, ajax

first post here. I have what I think is a security-related question, but I'm honestly not sure.

I'm building a mobile app using PhoneGap (basically an HTML page with jQuery/CSS). I have a call out to a .asmx webservice, like so:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://mydomain.com/customPage.asmx/LoginMember", 
    data: memberData, 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(msg) { 
            alert("This is my message: " + msg); 
    }, 
    error: authenticateFailed 
    });
```

When I test this using my desktop (Mac, Safari), the call is successful. My 'msg' variable contains some string-formatted XML. All good. Here's what my alert shows when the call is successful and data exists:

```
<User><Membership><Item>MemberLoginStatus</Item><Type>XML</Type><Status>1</Status><Description>Succeeded</Description></Membership></User>
```

But when I take the same code and move it onto my device (iPhone, PhoneGap), something else happens. The call is still successful and my success function fires, but my 'msg' variable has no data. I get this alert: "This is my message: null"

I've tried researching this, but can't seem to pinpoint what the actual source of the problem could be. I don't think it's my code, but am unsure whether it's an issue with jQuery, PhoneGap, or something else entirely.

As of now, my best guess is it's some kind of security issue. I noticed that when I test in Chrome, I get the same 'null' response as I do on my device. Could this possibly be due to the "Same Origin Policy?"

I've tried posting my question to the PhoneGap Google Group, the jQuery Forum, and haven't had much love. I would greatly appreciate any thoughts/advice, and am hoping someone else here has encountered this type of behavior before.

Thanks!
-Felix

//Edit: Fixed url typo. Added successful response data.

Comment: It's probably not a security issue because if it was it wouldn't have executed your `success` function, but of course you might want to take out "http://mydomain.com" from `url` and test it out just in case. I am confused why you are appending `msg` to the string if you are returning it as a `json` object though ... and then you said you said it's containing some "XML" ... :-/

Comment: Hi Haochi - The url needs to be absolute, as this will eventually be a standalone app. I'm appending the 'msg' var just so I can see what data is being returned.

Comment: Can you update your post to include what's the return value?

Comment: Updated! I'm accessing a webservice and using the documentation provided. Though I have dataType as JSON, what I'm getting is actually a string-formatted bit of XML. FYI I've tried changing the dataType to a variety of things (html, text, xml, script) with no luck.

Comment: Hmm, you are supposed to convert your output server-side. Simply telling jQuery that you want it in JSON format doesn't magically make the output JSON.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, the data is meant to be received as a string... so I can see about using a different data type. The big issue I still have though, regardless of dataType, is that I see data in one context, but not another. I've tried altering the dataType many times, with no success. So I'm not sure the dataType is what's causing a null value when I test things on my mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is that I'm an idiot. The domain I was testing on was a subdomain and on top of that... it's not a public site. I have the IP address in my hosts file on my machine, but (of course) not on my iPhone.

When I tried testing on a different/public site we have here... I now see data on my device.

Thanks so much Haochi and typeof, for your prompt and multiple replies. Out of all the other sites where I posted my question, you guys were incredibly quick with posting up some thoughts. In particular, it was typeof's question about the domain that got me thinking and realizing where the error came from.

I now feel like I've been trying to use my key to get into my house... and I've been standing in front of the wrong house. Incredibly embarrassing. But I see data now, and that's all that matters.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not quite there yet (at 11, need 15 rep). But will come back and do so when I'm able. Still learning the ropes around here, but quite enjoying both the site interface and the help from site members. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In your code you're missing the begging quote for your url property.

Assuming that's just a typo, have you tried switching User Agents in your desktop safari? (Must enable the Developer Menu item).  Switch your User Agent to "iPhone" and see if you get the null response.

Comment: Ah, yes - that's my typo. I didn't know about the User Agents option. Will give that a shot.

Comment: Just checked, and when I set the User Agent to iPhone... I get data successfully. Where I'm seeing problems on my iPhone though is within the app itself. I'm using PhoneGap, which takes my HTML/CSS/JS and packages it up as an app for the iPhone (different from the Safari browser on the device).

Comment: Try using the Chrome developer tools to see what's happening with the AJAX request/response.  Right-click the page and inspect, then click the Network tab.  Your Ajax call should be on the list - click it, and take a look at the content and headers tabs.

Comment: Ah! This is what I see in the Chrome Dev console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com/customPage.asmx/LoginMember. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." So does this mean that it looks to be the Same Origin Policy issue?

Comment: What is your domain name when testing this? Is it a file:// protocol?

Comment: Pardon my noob question, but are you asking if I'm hitting an actual www domain (as opposed to a file)? Sorry - I'm just not sure what you mean when you ask if it's a "file:// protocol."